# How to write to a txt file over multiple lines node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make my discord bot log messages into the HDD of my computer but I would like to be able to write over multiple lines otherwise its hard to read is there any chance someone knows how to do that? Here's my code

```js
let content = `[${date} - ${time}] ${message.guild.name} - ${message.guild.id}: ${message.channel.name} - ${message.channel.id}: ${message.author.tag} - ${message.author.id}: "${message}" https://discord.com/channels/${message.guild.id}/${message.channel.id}/${message.id}`;
    fs.appendFile(`A:/server-logs/${fileName}.txt`, content, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
```

Here's the result:

```
[26/6/2021 - 23:39:44] Dumb Stuff 101 - 836998621030383617: -general - 836998623170265130: Mushroomcrаft#7547 - 717070380795428866: "message 1" https://discord.com/channels/836998621030383617/836998623170265130/858476655978610698[26/6/2021 - 23:39:48] Dumb Stuff 101 - 836998621030383617: -general - 836998623170265130: Mushroomcrаft#7547 - 717070380795428866: "message 2" https://discord.com/channels/836998621030383617/836998623170265130/858476670830903317[26/6/2021 - 23:39:51] Dumb Stuff 101 - 836998621030383617: -general - 836998623170265130: Mushroomcrаft#7547 - 717070380795428866: "message 3" https://discord.com/channels/836998621030383617/836998623170265130/858476684222922793
```

What I would like:

```
[26/6/2021 - 23:39:44] Dumb Stuff 101 - 836998621030383617: -general - 836998623170265130: Mushroomcrаft#7547 - 717070380795428866: "message 1" https://discord.com/channels/836998621030383617/836998623170265130/858476655978610698
[26/6/2021 - 23:39:48] Dumb Stuff 101 - 836998621030383617: -general - 836998623170265130: Mushroomcrаft#7547 - 717070380795428866: "message 2" https://discord.com/channels/836998621030383617/836998623170265130/858476670830903317
[26/6/2021 - 23:39:51] Dumb Stuff 101 - 836998621030383617: -general - 836998623170265130: Mushroomcrаft#7547 - 717070380795428866: "message 3" https://discord.com/channels/836998621030383617/836998623170265130/858476684222922793
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Append it with a newline. (`\n` on Linux, `\r\n` on Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer tnx to that guy in the comments

```js
  let content = `\r\n [${date} - ${time}] ${message.guild.name} - ${message.guild.id}: ${message.channel.name} - ${message.channel.id}: ${message.author.tag} - ${message.author.id}: "${message}" https://discord.com/channels/${message.guild.id}/${message.channel.id}/${message.id}`;
    fs.appendFile(`A:/server-logs/${fileName}.txt`, content, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
```